# TypeError: <...> is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, class, ecmascript-6

So, I'm running into a problem and I'm not sure exactly how to resolve it. After reading through the ES6 doc's I think I have this set up correctly, yet when I call `<UserInstance>.getID()` I get the error:

> TypeError: currentUser.getID is not a function.

I know this may be a duplicate but in the other questions I've seen answer similar questions, none of them have allowed me to resolve this issue.

Here's my class definition:

```
import { v4String } from "uuid/interfaces";
class User {
    private id!: v4String;
    constructor() {
        this.getID = this.getID.bind(this);
        this.setID = this.setID.bind(this);
    }
    getID = () => this.id;
    setID = (id: v4String) => this.id = id;
}
export default User;
```

I'm pretty sure I have the class set up, but is there something I'm missing with the arrow function? It doesn't seem to matter if I set it up with the arrow function syntax, or set it up like

```
getID() {
   return this.id
}
```

Here's the code that's calling it, currentUser is provided by a context provider and injected into the props using a Higher Order Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const currentUser: User = this.props.currentUser;

        this.setState({ loading: true });

        const currentUserID = currentUser.getID(); <---- FAILS HERE
        const currentUserIDString = currentUserID.toString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? I don't think you can use `private` in JavaScript.

Comment: Seemed to work fine for me: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=21#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoaXoAckEsA3MAFwWnwBMBCALmghIIDsBzAbk22AHtnGkAV2AkeSABQBKNF2zYSAC3wQAdKwQkAkgBFoAXmiLlajTpUAjfM0rijESZzly7KxFt0GXbs5eu2l9o7YAL6y0Oru+tBS+gB8hgEqVEFY3h7RVPQCVqzSevEuVFHJ6KHovPwk0IKIKAbMCADucLVSnDXIrqba4gBEAIy9DuhgIMgk4h1IJu5SDkA).

Comment: Post the code where you set `currentUser` to an instance of `User` and where you call `currentUser.getID()`

Comment: @AlexWayne ok I'll post that shortly

Comment: @AskYous yes, using typescript

Comment: add `console.log(currentUser)` before the line the fails. What shows up in the console?

Comment: @AlexWayne an object with all the info, but it's not showing it as a User object, just a plain JS Object

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: currentUser.getID is not a function.

This error means that `currentUser` is some value which does not have a `getID` method on it. Your class is fine, so something is wrong with the value of `currentUser` and not the `User` class.

It appears that `currentUser` is a plain javascript object, and not an instance of your class.

```
const currentUser: User = this.props.currentUser;
```

This line does not make `currentUser` an instance of `User`, it merely a type hint for typescript. And it is a type hint that is incorrect.

Somewhere (where is up to you) you need to call `new User()` in order to be able to use the methods that you have defined on your user class. If you never call `new User()` then you do not have an instance of `User`, you just have a plain object.